# How to add to an existing hash in a instance variable in a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance variable with a hash as one of its properties. Assume that I don't want to use associations. I want to add to this hash and I'm currently doing it this way.

```
# dog.owners = { "Brad": "bar", "Matt": "foo"}
hash = dog.owners
hash["David"] = "foose"
dog.update(owners: hash)
```

Is there a way to do in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dog.update owners: dog.owners.merge( David: "foose" )`

#### Update

Please note that the comment in your question shows the hash keys being **symbols**, ie. in `{ "Brad": "bar" }` the presence of the `:` will make `"Brad"` into the symbol `:Brad` in the resulting hash.

This is important because later in your question you show `hash["David"] = "foose"` - that's adding a new element to the hash with a **string** key `"David"`!

This is important because `"David" != :David` so, for example:

```
[11] pry(main)> x = { "David": "symbol" }
=> {:David=>"symbol"}
[12] pry(main)> x["David"] = "string"
=> "string"
[13] pry(main)> x               
=> {:David=>"symbol", "David"=>"string"}
```

So, be careful there.

#### Second Update :)

All that being said, if this field is just coming out of a JSON(B) field from a DB or something then actually your keys might all be strings, in which case you should show your hash with `=>` not `:` (but maybe you were showing the raw JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). This lets ActiveRecord be a bit smarter about dealing with objects.

```
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :owners
end

...

dog = Dog.first
dog.owners["David"] = "foose"
dog.changes
dog.save
```